# Google Apps Marketplace icon missing from App Launcher

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have developed a Google Apps Marketplace app and recently received reports from our users, that the App Launcher ("grid") wouldn't show our app's icon anymore.

This is a screenshot how it looks for my personal Google Apps account when I'm on www.google.com:

[image: www.google.com]

And this is a screenshot from my account when I'm on admin.google.com/AdminHome:

[image: admin.google.com/AdminHome]

As you can see, only when I'm **on** the Google Apps account page, I can see icons of Marketplace apps. But it used to show up anywhere, also on www.google.com.

So Google must have changed something. The question is: *can we get it back to the old behaviour*?

PS: I know that it's just a link and one could simply bookmark it, but some of our customers are not really 'tech-savvy' and believe our app is 'gone completely' now. This is causing confusion everywhere.

Comment: As per my understanding, the Apps listing in the App Launcher ("grid") would show the list of apps when the user is logged in into one of Google products like Mail and Google + page. As you mentioned that your users are not tech-savvy, you can suggest them to click the "Mail" link in the Google search page and go to the Apps launcher Grid. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I didn't realize that it only shows up in Google products, but not the search. Good observation!